# join based on one column and closest time that isn't over

Tags: sql, r, oracle, dplyr, sqldf

Everything is working, but it is very slow iterating with two for loops.

Basically 2 data frames, one with and ID's and event time. The other with various IDs and readings (value and time stamp) every 10 seconds or so.

I am trying to join one table to another by matching both the ID, and the time at a specific interval before the event time, lets say 20 seconds.

Alternatively the data is in an oracle SQL server, which if I could do the table join's in SQL that works too.

```
readingdf <- data.frame(sensorID = c('100001','100001','100001','100001','100002','100002','100002','100002'),
                     readTime = as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-24 04:08:09 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:19 EDT",
                     "2017-07-24 04:08:29 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:39 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:09 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:19 EDT",
                     "2017-07-24 04:08:29 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:39 EDT"),tz="EST"),
                     Value = c('17.5','15.6','12.9','12.1','22.2', '24.5','19.7','20.1'))


df <- data.frame(sensorID = c('100001','100002','100001','100002','100001','100002','100001','100001'),
                     eventTime = as.POSIXct(c("2017-07-24 04:08:23 EDT","2017-07-24 04:08:25 EDT","2017-07-24 07:04:40 EDT",
                     "2017-07-24 02:19:30 EDT","2017-07-24 04:37:08 EDT","2017-07-24 04:19:59 EDT","2017-07-24 03:26:49 EDT",
                     "2017-07-24 03:58:17 EDT"),tz="EST"))
```

Comment: what do you mean interval 20 seconds? Please elaborate. if possible, can you paste the expected output here?. Thank you

Comment: If your tables are big you should do the join in the Oracle server: use something like `select * from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.sensorID=t2.sensorID and readTime <= eventTime and f(eventTime, readTime) <= 20)`, `f` being a function giving the difference between two datetimes in seconds (you have to define it).

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new column, `readTime_expand`, showing the next 20 seconds of `readTime`. After that, perform a join based on `sensorID` with `eventTime = readTime_expand`. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

readingdf2 <- readingdf %>%
  mutate(readTime_end = readTime + 20) %>%
  mutate(readTime_expand = map2(readTime, readTime_end, function(x, y){
    return(seq(x, y, by = 1))
  })) %>%
  unnest() 

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(readingdf2, by = c("sensorID", "eventTime" = "readTime_expand"))

df2
   sensorID           eventTime            readTime Value        readTime_end
1    100001 2017-07-24 04:08:23 2017-07-24 04:08:09  17.5 2017-07-24 04:08:29
2    100001 2017-07-24 04:08:23 2017-07-24 04:08:19  15.6 2017-07-24 04:08:39
3    100002 2017-07-24 04:08:25 2017-07-24 04:08:09  22.2 2017-07-24 04:08:29
4    100002 2017-07-24 04:08:25 2017-07-24 04:08:19  24.5 2017-07-24 04:08:39
5    100001 2017-07-24 07:04:40                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
6    100002 2017-07-24 02:19:30                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
7    100001 2017-07-24 04:37:08                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
8    100002 2017-07-24 04:19:59                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
9    100001 2017-07-24 03:26:49                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
10   100001 2017-07-24 03:58:17                <NA>  <NA>                <NA>
```